# Stage Manager autohides too fast, won't let me switch between stages when a window is expanded

Tags: macos, defaults, ventura, stage-manager

When Stage Manager is activated, it provides 3D previews of the spaces or stages on the left hand side that are always visible and take space but if you expand the current window over those spaces, they autohide and show up as 2D on top of the window if you move your pointer to the left edge of the screen so you can switch between them. My issue is that they hide immediately when I move the mouse even a little bit to the right but the correct behaviour would be to stay visible up until I move the pointer further away from the location so I can actually click them if I want.

Here is a short clip demonstrating how it behaves: https://streamable.com/bv354m

Here is a another one demonstrating how it is supposed to be: https://streamable.com/u51461

Over the years I might have fine tuned some settings through the `defaults` command in the terminal however deleting everything related from the `~/Library/Preferences` folder did not help to resolve the issue.

As I said, the Stage Manager works as expected a new user account and use it from there, which makes me to conclude that it's not a Beta related bug.

Any idea how to fix that?

PS: The OS is macOS 13.0 Ventura Beta 6 build 22A5331f

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because macOS Ventura is still in beta and the issue is most likely not expected behaviour and will be improved before official release

Comment: I don't think it's related to beta, as I explained above it works fine when a new user is created,

Comment: This Post on reddit suggests an incompatibility with some 3rd party software such as Monitor Control: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/vcq481/stage_manager_bug/

Comment: I've seen it but unfortunately removing Monitor Control didn't help in my case

Comment: Did you re-login after cleaning out Preferences?

Comment: Beta software is fine, but please put your macOS build version in so we know which beta has this behavior. We allow questions whether it’s a bug or not or beta or not, as long as other question quality standards are met. This is +1 in my opinion.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, just to be sure I reboot after I try anything.

Comment: @bmike Good point, it's macOS 13.0  build 22A5331f

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't test what this changes, but maybe it helps.

```
defaults read com.apple.WindowManager AutoHide
```

*default value = 0*

so you could change the value with:

```
defaults write com.apple.WindowManager AutoHide 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).